Target position given ship velocity and bullet velocity.
Let's say we have two ships. Both have a velocity and the first ship has a turret with autotargeting. For simplicity let's say the ship is a point and a bullet comes out of that point. The first ship fires, hitting the other ship. The equation I came up with for that is:
Ps = Position of the shooting ship.
Vb = Velocity of the bullet (unknown).
Vs = Velocity of the shooting ship.
Pt = Position of the target ship.
Vt = Velocity of the target ship.
t = Time to meet (unknown).
Ps+(Vb+Vs)t = Pt+Vtt
I am not really sure where to go from here. How do I find Vb? I have the magnitude (muzzle velocity) but direction I am not sure how to get.
Edit: I will update this as I work through it with help.
Xs+(Vxb+Vxs)t = Xt+Vxtt
Ys+(Vxb+Vxs)t = Yt+Vytt
Based on Ross Millikan's help...
Xs+(|Vb|$\cos \theta$+Vxs)t = Xt+Vxtt
Ys+(|Vb|$\sin \theta$+Vys)t = Yt+Vytt
Solved for $\theta$ with t still unknown, does everything up until this point make sense? I could make a fixed time lead which I believe would solve this.
$\theta$ = arccos((Xt-Xs)/t|Vb| + (Vxt-Vxs)/|Vb|)
But I don't think it's necessary to solve for $\theta$. This conclusion I came to works in my code. The problem is I don't know t so I am substituting a random constant:
Vxb = (Xt-Xs)/t|Vb| + (Vxt-Vxs)/|Vb|

You should know $V_s$ because the ship should know its velocity.  Note that you have two equations here, one for each axis, because it is a vector equation.  You have two unknowns, $t$ and the angle that $V_b$ makes with the axis.

Sorry, edited I meant the bullet's velocity. I am going to separate it component-wise then and start to try and work through it.

What is exactly your question ? If you are looking for the instant $t$ of impact, it seems that we haven't enough data...

You need an equation for every unknown. As presented, there is nothing to solve. Typically the firing speed of a bullet is known though, or can be researched.

I added more information to the post, hopefully this will make sense now. I think if I have a some sort of constant time lead this equation should be enough (if correct).

Still not clear. What is the target (pun...) of your exercise ? If it is a homework, what is the question that has been asked ?

lol it's not homework it's a project unrelated to school. Programming. Two ships have their own velocity. How do I calculate a bullet meeting from one ship to the other. We know the bullet's muzzle velocity.

Assuming I guessed the meanings of your added symbols correctly, then these are correct equations:
\begin{align}
X_s + (\lvert V_b\rvert \cos\theta + V_{xs}) t &= X_t + V_{xt} t, \\
Y_s + (\lvert V_b\rvert \sin\theta + V_{ys}) t &= Y_t + V_{yt} t.
\end{align}
It's just not clear to me how to solve for $\theta$ in this equations.
Here's a somewhat different suggestion.
Continuing from
$$
P_s + (V_b + V_s) t = P_t + V_t t,
$$
collect the known quantities on one side of the equation:
$$
V_b t = P_t - P_s + (V_t - V_s) t. \tag1\label{eq1}
$$
Let the angle of the vector $V_b$ with the vector $P_t - P_s$ be $\phi_b$ and let the angle of the vector $V_t - V_s$ with the vector $P_t - P_s$ be $\phi_{st}.$
For convenience in notation, let $V_{st} = V_t - V_s.$
We can then decompose each of the vectors $V_b$ and $V_{st}$ into a vector parallel to
$P_t - P_s$ and a vector perpendicular to $P_t - P_s.$
The component of $V_b$ perpendicular to $P_t - P_s$ is $V_b \sin\phi_b$
and the component of $V_{st}$ perpendicular to $P_t - P_s$ is $V_{st} \sin\phi_{st}.$
As the total displacement vectors on each side of Equation \eqref{eq1} are equal, their components perpendicular to $P_t - P_s$ also must be equal.
Writing this statement as an equation,
$$
V_b t \sin\phi_b =  V_{st} t \sin\phi_{st}. \tag2\label{eq2}
$$
(The vector $P_t - P_s$ of course has no component perpendicular to itself, so it contributes nothing to the right-hand side of Equation \eqref{eq2}.)
Divide both sides of Equation \eqref{eq2} by $t$:
$$
V_b \sin\phi_b =  V_{st} \sin\phi_{st}. \tag3\label{eq3}
$$
At this point you should know the values of everything in Equation \eqref{eq3} except $\phi_b$ and you should be able to solve for $\phi_b.$
